# What is Integrated Windows Authentication and what does it mean for me?

Tags: chrome, authentication, browser

I was looking through my Chromium browser settings and stumbled upon something called [`AuthServerAllowlist`](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=AuthServerAllowlist), which was set to the value `https://*`. Digging a little deeper, it looks like this is tied to something called [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication), which (based on a quick reading of the Wikipedia page) looks like a sort of single-sign-on feature, where I can automatically authenticate against a website in my browser using my Microsoft credentials that I logged into the computer with.

I get all that, and it makes sense... if this was a Windows computer. But I'm running Fedora Linux 37. I log into the computer with a local username and password that doesn't authenticate against any sort of cloud, and at no point is Microsoft involved in the transaction. And yet, it seems that Fedora has enabled this IWA feature in my browser.

What exactly is Chromium planning to use to authenticate me if it gets an IWA challenge? I understand the principle of the exchange on a Windows machine that was logged into using Microsoft cloud credentials, but that doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Googling "Chrome Linux IWA" leads me to https://community.rsa.com/t5/securid-community-blog/browser-configurations-for-the-rsa-securid-access-iwa-connector/ba-p/517512#toc-hId-1266182067, which says "As long as the Linux Machine is able to get a kerberos ticket ", and your first link talks about intranet websites, so presumably this is for Linux work devices configured with Kerberos for authentication to a corporate intranet website. Also you say "Fedora has enabled this", why? Couldn't it be something enabled by default?

Comment: @muru Chromium has `AuthServerAllowlist` listed under the "managed policies" section, which means it was set by something outside of Chromium. Since this is a personal laptop with no corporate policies, the only thing "outside of Chromium" is my operating system.

Comment: Ah, here it is: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/chrome-managed-by-organization/67189/2 => https://fedoramagazine.org/getting-set-up-with-fedora-project-services/ => 'In order to enable single sign-on out of the box for Google Chrome, Fedora needed to take advantage of certain features in Chrome that are intended for use in “managed” environments.'

Answer (score 0):

Chromium managed policies are installed in the directory `/etc/chromium/policies/managed`. After a fresh install of chromium, this directory is empty.

Check if you have files in this directory, you can then maybe determine their provenence with `dnf provides /path/to/file`.

Otherwise it means, you have the default settings.